# dark video with Skype

Tags: skype

When I use skype the video looks really dark (both to me and the other person).  But it doesn't seem to be a problem with the webcam itself, because with Cheese the image looks fine.

Comment: i would look into color correction options within skype.  i know cheese automagically adjusts for light on my box

Comment: I agree, skype is pretty inflexible. Does the same problem happen with video chat in Empathy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try this, it works on Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and I think it'll work on your computer too :)

http://severity1.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/fixing-skype-webcam-is-very-dark-problem-in-ubuntu-karmic-and-lucid/

Comment: Please include details from the link.

Answer (score 4):

`v4l2ucp` package contains a video-settings GUI. You can use it to alter the skype video settings during a video call (run `v4l2ucp`).

[image]

Checking "Exposure, Auto priority" helped me.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit of a hassle but Webcam Studio is an amazing piece of software that will allow you to stream multiple video inputs (your webcam, with color correction and effects) to a virtual device that you can use within skype. 
You can get it/investigate here http://www.ws4gl.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
luvcview
```

type it in the console and configure your webcam from there. At the end press F1 to save the changes.

Comment: with skype 4 it seams, changes are no longer in sync between skype and luvcview

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a long time.  Nothing (including Cheese, luvcview) worked and I almost gave up on using Linux Skype. I came across the following and the rest is history.

My Skype webcam is now very nice.

http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-webcam-problem-in-skype.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Open Skype
2. Go to Skype -> Options -> Video Devices
3. Turn off 'Enable Skype video' and 'Disable Auto-exposure'
4. Click Apply
5. Turn those options back on
6. Click Apply

It works every time but it's not a permanent fix. It needs to be done after every boot session.

Hope this helped.